# How to show image after jQuery positioning it

Tags: jquery, html, css

The script is:

```
function correctMe(){
var top_move = parseInt($('#image').css('height')) / 2;
$('#image').css({position : 'relative', top: '50%', marginTop: '-' + top_move + 'px'});
    $('#image').fadeIn(100);
}
```

And the html is:

```
<img id="image" onload="correctMe()" src="image.jpg" style="display: none;"/>
```

My goal is to:

1. load the image
2. position it via jQuery
3. show it.

My code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `display: none` try `visibility: hidden`.

```
<img id="image" onload="correctMe()" src="image.jpg" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
```

And then:

```
function correctMe(){
    var $image = $('#image'),
        top_move = parseInt($image.css('height'), 10) / 2;

    $image
        .css({
            position: 'relative',
            top: '50%',
            marginTop: - top_move,
            opacity: 0,
            visibility: visible
        })
        .animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 100); 
}
```

PS: The reason for not setting `opacity: 0` in the style directly is because it won't work in IE<9.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bw2vy/1/

Have you tried:

```
function correctMe(){
var top_move = parseInt($('#image').css('height')) / 2;
$('#image').css({position : 'relative', top: '50%', marginTop: '-' + top_move + 'px'});
$('#image').fadeIn(100); 
}
```

Wrap the image in a div? Try initially without the onload - use an onclick in a href to check it works.

```
<div style="padding:20px; background: #ffcc00;"><img id="image" src="../images/icons/folder_magnify.png" width="50" height="50" /></div>

<a href="#" onclick="correctMe();">movenshow</a>
```

Then put to:

```
<div style="padding:20px; background: #ffcc00;"><img id="image" onload="correctMe()" src="../images/icons/folder_magnify.png" width="50" height="50" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

Seems to do it for me.

Comment: I have tried  display: inline (which is my default css style for the image)

Comment: ah, was going to say I have it working here. Will check position

Answer (score 0):

Try this

first make sure you not have a multiple #image for element

```
function correctMe(){
    var top_move = parseInt($('#image').css('height')) / 2;

    $('#image').css("position" : 'relative');
    $('#image').css("top" : 'relative');
    $('#image').css("marginTop" : '-'+top_move.toString()+'px');

    $('#image').fadeIn(100);
}
```

Comment: Best to cache the `$('#image')` selector, no point in getting it 5 times.

Comment: I never more elements with same IDs. My positioning works, no problem with that. But it doesn't work while the image is not shown. :/

Example: http://pixpresso.mycyberlove.com/photo/view/443

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this well, the problem is the image is not faded in correctly, the rest working fine. That is also what i observe on the site link you provided. The reason why you get no fade-in is because the image is not hidden. You wouild have to hide the image first, either with css or js, to be able to fade it in...

Also, i don't understand why you set some static properties via jquery. Why not just declare them in your stylesheet? I would only use js to set the margin-top, as it is the only calculated value.

As mentionned by others, caching jQuery selectors is always a good idea, improves your performance!

I set up a small example for you to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/HRejn/

jquery:

```
var $image = $('#image');
var top_move = parseInt($image.height() / 2);
alert(top_move);
$image.css('margin-top', top_move + 'px');
$image.fadeIn(100);
```

css:

```
#image {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    display: block; 
    display: none;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this Helps**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Position And Load</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imageLoader" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:1px solid #B0B0B0">
        <img id="image" onload="loadImage();" src="http://www.paulmarc.org/sites/default/files/books/images/tux.png" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImage(){
        var top_move = parseInt($('#image').css('height')) / 2;
        $('#image').css({
            position: 'relative',
            top: '50%',
            marginTop: '-' + top_move + 'px',
        }); 
        $('#image').fadeIn(1000, function(){                
            $('#image').css({
                height:'128px',
                width:'128px',
                display:'block'
            });         
        });     
    }
    </script>
</html>
```